# Can't render multiple inputs within a form tag using TagHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, will-paginate, hidden-field

I am trying to insert a form into `will_paginate` so the user can enter a page number and hit enter to navigate to that page.

In order to do this, I am passing the `params` from the request into `will_paginate` and adding them as hidden inputs to the form. That way, all of those values will be added to the URL along with the page number (the only visible input) when the form submits.

The problem is that my inputs seem to be getting interpreted as the text of their parent node, instead of child html nodes. Here's the `to_html` method:

```
def to_html
  inputs = [@template.tag(:input, :name => 'page', :value => current_page, :size => 1)] 
  @options[:params].delete(:page)
  @options[:params].delete(:action)
  @options[:params].each do |k, v|
    inputs << @template.tag(:input, :type => 'hidden', :name => k, :value => v)
  end 

  html = inputs.join
  form = @template.content_tag(:form, @template.content_tag(:div, html))
  previous_page + form + next_page
end
```

And here's the form as it appears on the page:

```
<form>
  <div><input name="page" size="1" value="1" /><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" /><input name="full_query" type="hidden" value="{&quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;&quot;, &quot;organization_name&quot;=&gt;&quot;&quot;, &quot;contact_type_id&quot;=&gt;&quot;&quot;}" /><input name="commit" type="hidden" value="Generate List" /><input name="controller" type="hidden" value="contacts/contacts" /></div>
</form>
```

If I only put `inputs.first` as the content of the `div`, it works as expected. But as soon as I insert multiple inputs, it gets interpreted as text. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do

```
html = inputs.join.html_safe
```

Now to the interesting part: why does `inputs.first` work, but `inputs.join` doesn't? Well, `inputs.first` is actually the output of `@template.tag(...)`, which [returns an html_safe string](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L65). But, when you do a Ruby join on multiple html_safe strings, you get a non-html_safe string.

In other words, with `content_tag(:div, inputs.first)`, `inputs.first` is an html_safe string; with `content_tag(:div, inputs.join)`, `inputs.join` is not an html_safe string.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It seems another solution would be to do `@template.content_tag(:div, html, nil, false)` where false is telling `content_tag` not to escape attributes or the inner text.

Comment: You're right that adding `html_safe` is needed, but this will still leave the problem that nested values will be passed in a single input as a hash, in this case `<input name="full_query" type="hidden" value="{"name"=>"", "organization_name"=>"", "contact_type_id"=>""}" />`. So I don't think your solution will work as-is, even after turning off sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand the problem, but here are a few things I noticed.

First, you don't need to pass all the values in `params` from the request as hidden values to the form. You've removed `page` and `action`, but left the `controller` (which appears as the last hidden input in the form that is generated).

But more to the point, I don't think you need to be deleting these from `params` and then iterating through whatever is left. What you want are the previous form input values, which appear to be stored in `params[:full_query]` (I guess your form is for an object called `full_query`?), so why don't you just iterate through that? Then you don't need to bother with `delete(:page)`, `delete(:action)` etc. Assign the values to `full_query[<KEY>]`, i.e. `full_query[name]`, `full_query[organization_name]`, etc.

Like this:

```
def to_html
  inputs = [@template.tag(:input, :name => 'page', :value => current_page, :size => 1)] 
  @options[:params][:full_query].each do |k, v|
    inputs << @template.tag(:input, :type => 'hidden', :name => "full_query[#{k}]", :value => v)
  end

  html = inputs.join
  form = @template.content_tag(:form, @template.content_tag(:div, html))
  previous_page + form + next_page
end
```

I haven't tested this so I'm not sure it will work, but I think this is the general gist of what you need to do.

Comment: Hi. He will still have the same issue, as inputs.join creates a non html_safe string. When a non html_safe string is passed to `content_tag`, the input string will be sanitized. But, about everything else you said, I don't think we have enough context to make assumptions.

Comment: I agree that `html_safe` is part of the solution, but you're still left with a nested values problem. See my comment on your answer above.

Comment: @shioyama: Thanks for your suggestion, you are mostly correct. I do need some of the params outside of `full_query`, but mostly what I do need is inputs with a name of `full_query[field_name]`. I accepted Andrew's answer because the purpose of the question was really to figure out why my inputs weren't rendering properly, but you definitely get an upvote from me!